# where is internal file stored in an android project?

Tags: java, android

In my project I have to make a text file and read particulars from that file. I need to know where I should place the file in directory so that I can successfully read it in my java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are files that your app downloads or creates, you should follow the guidelines for using [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) or [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), if it is included in the apk, then the file should go in `/assets/` and you can access it using the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).

Answer (score 2):

That should go in `/assets/`

Read this tutorial also about [Android Beginners: Intro to Resources and Assets](http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/06/14/Android-Beginners-Intro-to-Resources-and-Assets.aspx)

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream stream = null;
try {
    stream = assetManager.open("file.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle
}
finally {
         if (stream != null) {
               try {
                   stream.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {}
         }
}
```